# DateFormat in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get the hour, minute and am/pm seperately using the bellow format in flutter?

The below is the piece of code i tried,

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
var formatTime = DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(now);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var formatTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(now);

  //you can get hour minute directly
  var hhDirect = now.hour;
  var mmDirect = now.minute;

  //or your can get with this method
  var splitTimeAndAmPm = formatTime.split(' ');
  var splitHHandMM = splitTimeAndAmPm.first.split(':');

  var am_pm = splitTimeAndAmPm.last;
  var hh = splitHHandMM.first;
  var mm = splitHHandMM.last;

  print('HH Direct: ' + hhDirect.toString());
  print('MM Direct: ' + mmDirect.toString());
  print('HH: ' + hh);
  print('MM: ' + mm);
  print('AmPm: ' + am_pm);
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get the hours and minutes seperately?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take a look. If you found your answer with my solution, please mark it as your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: This answer would be enhanced by showing the outcome of the various code examples.  I am wondering how the code above affects the default DateTime.now.